# Emacs is using the wrong SHELL

Tags: spacemacs, osx

I'm using emacs 26.1 and spacemacs (`emacs-plus` from homebrew and spacemacs is from the develop branch). I've configured my local shell to use ZSH from homebrew as well (installed to `/usr/local/bin/zsh`).

When I start emacs, `(getenv SHELL)` shows `/bin/bash`.

The first expression in `dotspacemacs/user-init` is:

```
(when (memq window-system '(mac ns x))
  (setenv "SHELL" "/usr/local/bin/zsh")
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))
```

What's the appropriate way to get emacs/spacemacs to pick up the local environment?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be related to the following bug https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/10906